# Creating Java String with Escape Sequence

Tags: java, string, escaping

I am trying to create a String which has the below value, but I am getting a syntax error. can anyone please help on this.

```
tr -d '\15\32' < shell.sh > com.sh
```

I need the final output in a String something like the above. This is what I've tried:

```
String s = "tr -d '\15\32' < shell.sh > com.sh";
```

But I am getting an error for the above code.

Comment: "i am getting error" is never enough information. *Always* give the exact error message.

Answer (score 2):

A `\`  in a string literal starts an [escape sequence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6).

Double the `\` in a string literal :

```
String s = "tr -d '\\15\\32' < shell.sh > com.sh";
```